# Loading multiple assemblies from resources

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, .net-assembly

To avoid having to include two assemblies with my exe file I have included them as embedded resources in my WPF application. Now I can load the first assembly by doing this:

```
static Assembly ResolveAssembly(object sender, ResolveEventArgs args)
{
    string resourceName = "someDLLfileInResources";
    using (Stream stream = parentAssembly.GetManifestResourceStream(resourceName))
    {
        byte[] block = new byte[stream.Length];
        stream1.Read(block, 0, block.Length);
        return Assembly.Load(block);
    }
}
```

This works and the program will run without the first DLL. Now, if I repeat the process for the 2nd DLL file it will no longer run without the first (however I dont have to include the 2nd). So it seems only to work on the last loaded assembly. Am I doing it wrong?

Thank you

Comment: Do not repeat tags in question titles. Thank you.

Comment: Are there any dependencies between those two assemblies?

Comment: Have you considered using ILmerge?

Answer (score 0):

How are you "repeating" the process? I see one static method that ruturns your assembly, if it gets called twice, are you overwriting your first assembly with the second one?

Or are you calling this method once, handling both dll's? Because you only return 1 Assembly in the end of course...